# ASP.NET WEB API - CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver - force to ignore specific endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-filters

I am using ASP.NET web api. To provide support for camel case for the properties that an end point returns, I have added this code:

```
//Support camel casing
            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

This is working fine but I want to add an exception for one of the endpoints. Which will ensure when the data is returned from that end point, properties are not camel cased. How can I add this exception or a single endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make control if you are applying a global `camel case configuration` 
AFAK the only way to achieve this is by using  `ActionFilterAttribute`
something like the following

```
public class CamelCasingFilterAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private JsonMediaTypeFormatter _camelCasingFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        public CamelCasingFilterAttribute()
        {
            _camelCasingFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            ObjectContent content = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
            if (content != null)
            {
                if (content.Formatter is JsonMediaTypeFormatter)
                {
                    actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(content.ObjectType, content.Value, _camelCasingFormatter);
                }
            }
        }
    }



  public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        [CamelCasingFilter]
        public IEnumerable<Test> Get()
        {
            return new Test[] {new Test() {Prop1 = "123", Prop2 = "3ERr"}, new Test() {Prop1 = "123", Prop2 = "3ERr"}};  
        }

        // GET api/values/5

        public Test Get(int id)
        {

            return new Test() {Prop1 = "123", Prop2 = "3ERr"};  
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

if you try to call the first action the answer will like the follwing

```
[{"prop1":"123","prop2":"3ERr"},{"prop1":"123","prop2":"3ERr"}]
```

and for the second action given that there is no filter you will get something like this

```
{
    "prop1": "123",
    "prop2": "3ERr"
}
```

**Note**  if you want to make it easy controlling camelCase over an entire controller, try to put your action that you want it to send back the answer in a not CamelCase in a controller apart but, for the rest apply this Filter on a controller level if you want.
**More** you should delete the GlobalConfiguration to get this

Comment: +1. Thank you or quick reply. I am aware of this option. But I do not want to remove global setting and then add filter attribute on every endpoint unless I really have to. I will wait or some more time.